# Creating a countdown for 30 days

Tags: php

I'm trying to create some kind of countdown. I'm creating this community, and I want to create some kind of VIP, which has to last for 30 days.

So, when a user have bought this VIP, I will be inserting the current date('d'); to the database.

Then I have to -1 every day. How would you do this? I've tried with some mktime(); but that definitely won't work out for me.

I've tried this link: http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/9471.aspx, without any results.

Thanks in forward :-)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What have you tried so far and what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: I would like to know, what I have to do. Do I have to update all users with VIP every day the clock is past 00:00 and -1 for all? Or is there some smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the end time in the database, and check to see if `now < end time`. Avoid having flags that you have to update on a schedule.

Comment: When would you 'check' for this? When the user is logged in, or what's  up?

Comment: "Avoid having flags that you have to update on a schedule." what do you mean with this?

Comment: @Kolind — You'd check at any time you care about finding out if the user has VIP status or not.

Comment: Do the check lazily. As soon as the VIP status is required to be displayed or used in some application logic, you can do this check to find out if the user is a VIP or not.

Comment: @Kolind — That means do what the first sentence says and not what you suggest in the question.

Comment: @Quentin Now, how would you store the end time in db? Would you use time(); or something?

Comment: Depends on the database. If it had a datetime data type, I'd use that (probably in combination with something like `NOW()` for queries).

Comment: @Quentin I get, that I have to '+' the time() + (something); but, what would I '+' the time() with to get 30 days?

Comment: @Kolind: Depends on what `time()` returns. If it is a UNIX timestamp, then you have to add the amount of seconds equal to 30 days.

Comment: I guess it's UNIX, and nice, I found this link; http://www.convertunits.com/from/30+days/to/seconds .. I guess I know what to do now, thanks everybody who'd helped me with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the current date as `time()`. This function returns the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.

Since you have stored the start date, you can simply calculate the end date by adding `30 days * 24 hours / day * 60 minutes / hour * 60 seconds / minute` to the start date.

To find out if the VIP status is still active, you can compare if the end time is already in the past; or - by checking the difference between the current `time()` and the stored time - find out how many days remain.

Answer (score 1):

when user buy VIP from your site, save date when they buy in your db and whenever you show vip in page, check with current date if that is less than 30 days VIP is still active else VIP is expired.

```
$boughtDate = new DateTime("2011-11-20");
$currentDate = new DateTime("2011-12-23");

$interval = $boughtDate ->diff($currentDate );
if (($interval->d) > 30 ) {
    echo "VIP expired";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply store a full timestamp when someone buys VIP permissions. Then you can get the remaining time by doing `VIP_DURATION_IN_SECONDS - (time() - $vip_bought_time)`. As soon as this returns zero or a negative value, the VIP status expired.

It doesn't really matter when you check it - you could do it in a cronjob running daily/hourly/whatever or simply on each page load. Since you probably store this value in the user table you already have it available anyway - so the check is super-cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the expiration timestamp to your database and in your script you just do something like this:

```
$expirationDate = *query it from databse*;
$now = time();
if ($expirationDate > $now)
{
  //grant access
}
else
{
  //deny access
}
```

Answer (score -2):

may be you are looking for a [countdown script](http://www.minisitegallery.com/2020/) like this.

Just use this [documentation](http://www.minisitegallery.com/blog/php-javascript-countdown-script-with-timezone-setting.html) to implement it.